# How to add random action to Python?

Tags: python, random

I've been coding an adventure game in Python myself and through YouTube and stuff I found online, but I want to add a part where You gotta get on this boat but a ticket costs $10 (Which you have an option to get earlier).

But say you *didn't* get the 10 earlier, you have another option to run past the guy who's asking you to pay for it (Which I guess you Could also do even *if* you have the 10 and just save money). But if you have $10, you just go through, and if you don't, you just restart and it runs sys.exit()

As of writing, the code looks like this:

```
print("A man offers you a trip to the eastern side of the village via boat")

print(
    "as a bridge has not been constructed yet, but it will cost $10, do you give him it ($10 Required) or try run past him(Free)")

check_inv = input()

if "$10" not in inv:
    print("He caught you making a run for it! restart game")
    sys.exit()

else:
    
  print("Let's see if you have enough...")
    
  print(inv)
    
  print("You have enough and cross the river")
    
  removeFrominventory("$10")
```

I know how to write a random number generator as it was another beginner project I was advised to work on, but I want to to be that if you type 'Run' you will have a 50/50 chance to be able to outrun him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want it to be like the RNG in pokemon or want to create a coin flip event, you could either create a list of `list = [0,1]` and use `random.choice(list)` or you could use `randrange()` to get a number b/w 0 and 100. Let's say the chances to outrun are `x%`. If the value obtained from randrange is less than x, you outrun else you don't. You can create a function like:

```
def RNG(probability):
    Generate Random num b/w 0 and 100
    if num<probability:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I would prefer the RNG function. Though it is time and memory consuming, it can be reused in the code again and again.